# Giving the fulll code of merging of image and song for generating video files?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Say, the following code is supposed hold our video and audio files:

```
AVMutableComposition* mixComposition = [AVMutableComposition composition];

//Now first load your audio file using AVURLAsset. Make sure you give the correct path of your videos.
NSURL *audio_url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"" ofType:@"mp3"]];
AVURLAsset  *audioAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:audio_url options:nil];
CMTimeRange audio_timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, audioAsset.duration);

//Now we are creating the first AVMutableCompositionTrack containing our audio and add it to our AVMutableComposition object.
AVMutableCompositionTrack *b_compositionAudioTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
[b_compositionAudioTrack insertTimeRange:audio_timeRange ofTrack:[[audioAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];

//Now we will load video file.
NSURL *video_url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"" ofType:@"mp4"]];
AVURLAsset  *videoAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:video_url options:nil];
CMTimeRange video_timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero,audioAsset.duration);

//Now we are creating the second AVMutableCompositionTrack containing our video and add it to our AVMutableComposition object.
AVMutableCompositionTrack *a_compositionVideoTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
[a_compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:video_timeRange ofTrack:[[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];

//decide the path where you want to store the final video created with audio and video merge.
NSArray *dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *outputFilePath = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"FinalVideo.mov"]];
NSURL *outputFileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:outputFilePath];
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:outputFilePath])
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:outputFilePath error:nil];

//Now create an AVAssetExportSession object that will save your final video at specified path.
AVAssetExportSession* _assetExport = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];
_assetExport.outputFileType = @"https://www.apple.com/quicktime";
_assetExport.outputURL = outputFileUrl;

[_assetExport exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:
 ^(void ) {

     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         [self exportDidFinish:_assetExport];
     });
 }
 ];
}

- (void)exportDidFinish:(AVAssetExportSession*)session {
    if(session.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted) {
        NSURL *outputURL = session.outputURL;
        ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
        if([library videoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum:outputURL]) {
            [library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:outputURL
                                        completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {
                                            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                                if (error) {
                                                    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"  message:@"Video Saving Failed"  delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil, nil];
                                                    [alert show];
                                                } else {
                                                    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                                                          initWithTitle:@"Video Saved" message:@"Saved To Photo Album"      delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
                                                    [alert show];
                                                    [self loadMoviePlayer:outputURL];
                                                }
                                            });
                                        }];
        }
    }
    audioAsset = nil;
    videoAsset = nil;
    [activityView stopAnimating];
    [activityView setHidden:YES];
}


-(void)loadMoviePlayer:(NSURL*)moviePath {

    moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
                   initWithContentURL:moviePath];
    moviePlayer.view.hidden = NO;
    moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, vwMoviePlayer.frame.size.width,
                                        vwMoviePlayer.frame.size.height);
    moviePlayer.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];


    [vwMoviePlayer addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
    [vwMoviePlayer setHidden:NO];

}



- (IBAction)mergeandsave:(id)sender {
    [activityView setHidden:NO];
    [activityView startAnimating];
    [vwMoviePlayer setHidden:YES];
    [self performSelector:@selector(mergeAndSave) withObject:nil afterDelay:.6];

}
```

***Question:***

How to merge audio and image to generate video file?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: how to merge audio and image to generate video